# The Program doesn't respond and gets frozen when executed .exe from the debug folder unlike from Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, exe

I have a set of ProgressBars that progress while the process is being carried out. It progresses all fine when executed from Visual Studio but when I try to execute from the .exe file from the debug folder, the program freezes and doesn't respond although the process is working fine (data gets inserted into DB).

**Edit:** The data being inserted is huge (33000+ records) but doesn't hang when executed from Visual studio unlike debug folder's .exe execution

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you inserting in a loop? Could you trigger a screen refresh every n records and allow the gui to catch up? Or process the inserts on a thread and await the result?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. As it stands, your question is off-topic because you don't explain what behaviour you're  getting and what errors you get and on what line they occur. Don't let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks